# How to change the HTML rendering of a Pandoc element?

Tags: lua, pandoc

I'm trying to customize the default HTML output of footnotes from an .odt file.

For example a file with a footnote like this:

> Some text with a footnote<sup>1</sup>

Will render the HTML output below:

```html
<ol class="footnotes">
    <li id="fn1" role="doc-endnote">
        <p>Content of footnote number 1. <a href="#fnref1" class="footnote-back" role="doc-backlink">↩︎</a></p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I want instead to have a flat paragraph to be output, with hardcoded a number like following:

```html
<p>1. Content of footnote number 1. <a href="#fnref1" class="footnote-back" role="doc-backlink">↩︎</a></p>
```

I've used parts of [`sample.lua`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/sample.lua) from the Pandoc repo but is not working, the process is blocked by this error:

```
$ pandoc --lua-filter=my-filter.lua file.odt -o file.html

Error running filter my-filter.lua:
my-filter.lua:7: bad argument #1 to 'gsub' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'string.gsub'
        my-filter.lua:7: in function 'Note'
```

Below is my attempted script, I guess I'm naively overlooking something obvious or I've badly understood how filters work.

```lua
-- Table to store footnotes, so they can be included at the end.
local notes = {}

function Note(s)
    local num = #notes + 1
    -- insert the back reference right before the final closing tag.
    s = string.gsub(s,
          '(.*)</', '%1 <a href="#fnref' .. num ..  '">&#8617;</a></')
    -- add a list item with the note to the note table.
    table.insert(notes, '<p id="fn' .. num .. '">' .. num .. '. ' .. s .. '</p>')
    -- return the footnote reference, linked to the note.
    return '<a id="fnref' .. num .. '" href="#fn' .. num ..
            '"><sup>' .. num .. '</sup></a>'
end

function Pandoc (doc)
    local buffer = {}
    local function add(s)
    table.insert(buffer, s)
    end
    add(doc)
    if #notes > 0 then
    for _,note in pairs(notes) do
      add(note)
    end
    end
    return table.concat(buffer,'\n') .. '\n'
end
```

---

Update

Tweaking part of what @tarleb answered I've managed now to modify the inline note reference link, but apparently the second function is not rendering the list of footnotes at the end of the document. What's missing?

```lua
local notes = pandoc.List{}

function Note(note)

    local num = #notes + 1

    -- add a list item with the note to the note table.
    notes:insert(pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(note.content))

    -- return the footnote reference, linked to the note.
    return pandoc.RawInline('html', '<a id="fnref' .. num .. '" href="#fn' .. num ..
            '"><sup>' .. num .. '</sup></a>')
end

function Pandoc (doc)
  doc.meta['include-after'] = notes:map(
    function (content, i)
      -- return a paragraph for each note.
        return pandoc.Para({tostring(i) .. '. '} .. content)
    end
  )
  return doc
end
```

Comment: The first parameter of `Note`, `s` is not a string but rather a `Note` element: https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-note. You probably want `s.tag`?

Comment: Yea because I used parts of a writer instead of a filter as explained by @tarleb.

Comment: Make sure to run pandoc with `-s`/`--standalone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed after some trial and error to get a result that is working as intended, but "stylistically" not *absolutely perfect*.

Please read my commentary below mostly as an excercise, I'm trying to understand better how to use this great tool the way *I* wanted, not the way any reasonable person should in a productive way (or *any* way at all). ;)

What I'd like to improve:

- I have to wrap the `p` elements in a `div` because as of Pandoc 2.18 [is not possible to provide direct attributes to a Paragraph](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684). This is a minor code bloat but acceptable.
- I'd like to use a `section` element instead of a `div` to put all the notes at end of document (used in the `Pandoc` function), but I haven't found a way to create a [`RawBlock`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.rawblock) element and then add the note blocks to it.

I'm tottaly not proficient in Lua and barely grasped a few concept of how Pandoc works, so I'm pretty confident that what I've done below is non optimal. Suggestions are welcome!

```lua
-- working as of Pandoc 2.18

local notes = pandoc.List{}

function Note(note)

    local num = #notes + 1

    -- create a paragraph for the note content
    local footNote = pandoc.Para(
        -- Prefix content with number, ex. '1. '
        {tostring(num) .. '. '} ..
        -- paragraph accept Inline objects as content, Note content are Block objects
        -- and must be converted to inlines
        pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(note.content) ..
        -- append backlink
        { pandoc.RawInline('html', '<a class="footnote-back" href="#fnref' .. num ..  '" role="doc-backlink"> ↩︎</a>')}
        )

    -- it's not possible to render paragraphs with attribute elements as of Pandoc 2.18
    -- so wrap the footnote in a <div> with attributes and append the element to the list
    notes:insert(pandoc.Div(footNote, {id = 'fn' .. num, role = 'doc-endnote'}))

    -- return the inline body footnote reference, linked to the note.
    return pandoc.RawInline('html', '<a id="fnref' .. num .. '" href="#fn' .. num ..
            '"><sup>' .. num .. '</sup></a>')
end

function Pandoc (doc)

  if #notes > 0 then
  -- append collected notes to block list, the end of the document
  doc.blocks:insert(
    pandoc.Div(
      notes:map(
        function (note)
            return note
        end
      ),
      -- attributes
      {class = 'footnotes', role = 'doc-endnotes'}
    )
  )
  end

  return doc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sample.lua` is an example of a custom Lua writer, not a Lua filter. They can look similar, but are quite different. E.g., filter functions modify abstract document elements, while functions in custom writers generally expect strings, at least in the first argument.

A good way to go about this in a filter could be to place the custom rendering in the `include-after` metadata:

```lua
local notes = pandoc.List{}

function Pandoc (doc)
  doc.blocks:walk {
    Note = function (note)
      notes:insert(pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(note.content))
      -- Raw HTML goes into an RawInline element
      return pandoc.RawInline('html', 'footnote link HTML goes here')
    end
  }

  doc.meta['include-after'] = notes:map(
    function (content, i)
      -- return a paragraph for each note.
      return pandoc.Para({tostring(i) .. ' '} .. content)
    end
  )
  return doc
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the writer/filter distinction. I've tried to apply your filter as is, but nothing is really happening AFAICT. I expected 'footnote link HTML goes here' to replace all footnotes but I found everything rendered normally as before. Am I missing something? I'm using the latest release version 2.18. I corrected a missing `end` in the Note function.

Comment: Also full disclosure I'm a total lua rookie, hope I'm not missing something trivial.

Comment: I've made a small progress, I've updated my question. Thank you for your time!